# Setting local variable containing data from database to global format

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this variable containing data from database in if statement. How to set it to global or is there any way to access those data outside of that if statement?

```
if(condition){
   $data = G_Employee::find()->single('id', 'some value'); 
}
```

Comment: Outside of that `if`? If the line runs, it's already available outside the `if`. https://3v4l.org/2VY2f

Comment: It says that I am using an undefined variable when I access its data. I did it like this: $data->id; And btw, I put that code inside another if statement. Does doing that cause me to get this error?

Comment: Perhaps your `condition` is returning `false`? If the body of the `if` doesn't run, then `$data` won't be set in which case you should set a default value outside of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one to access data outside of that if statement

```
$GLOBALS['data'];
     if(condition){
       $data = G_Employee::find()->single('id', 'some value'); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable for your class and use/access it with `$this`

Example:

```
class MY_CLASS extends CI_Controller {

   protected $data;

   public function MY_FUNCTION {
      if(condition){
         $this->data = G_Employee::find()->single('id', 'some value'); 
      }

      var_dump($this->data); //$this->data is accessible from anywhere in your class. 
                            //You can check if it has the value you want
   }

}
```

Comment: I am coding in view. Will it be applicable in view, the "$this->data"?